# ASP, EF with Relations: Cannot access API after deploy due to more data causing timeout error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

The API has no issue at the beginning, it was working fine. But when more and more data was accumulated in the database (mariadb), the event participants cannot get their workshop data, such as their attendance records, their history sessions, the API fails.

I tried to solve but did not find a solution, how to can I solve this timeout issue?

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Participant")]
[ValidateReferrerAttribute]
public async Task<ParticipantSessionDto> GetSessions()
{
    if (User.Identity is { IsAuthenticated: true })
    {
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(
            cfg => cfg.CreateProjection<Participant, ParticipantSessionDto>());

        return await _entities
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.CheckIns)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Session)
            .Include(x => x.Events)
            .Include(x => x.Sessions)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Event)
            .Include(x => x.Sessions)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Speakers)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Avatar)
            .Include(x => x.Sessions)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Materials)
            .ProjectTo<ParticipantSessionDto>(configuration)
            .FirstAsync(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The exception log

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): The Command Timeout expired before the operation completed.
     ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (125): Operation canceled
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Int32>.GetResult(Int16 token)
       at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.SocketByteHandler.DoReadBytesAsync(Memory`1 buffer) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Protocol/Serialization/SocketByteHandler.cs:line 109
       at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.SocketByteHandler.DoReadBytesAsync(Memory`1 buffer) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Protocol/Serialization/SocketByteHandler.cs:line 109
       at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.BufferedByteReader.ReadBytesAsync(IByteHandler byteHandler, ArraySegment`1 buffer, Int32 totalBytesToRead, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Protocol/Serialization/BufferedByteReader.cs:line 34
       at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.ProtocolUtility.<ReadPacketAfterHeader>g__AddContinuation|2_0(ValueTask`1 payloadBytesTask, Int32 payloadLength, ProtocolErrorBehavior protocolErrorBehavior, Exception packetOutOfOrderException) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Protocol/Serialization/ProtocolUtility.cs:line 434
       at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.ProtocolUtility.<DoReadPayloadAsync>g__AddContinuation|5_0(ValueTask`1 readPacketTask, BufferedByteReader bufferedByteReader, IByteHandler byteHandler, Func`1 getNextSequenceNumber, ArraySegmentHolder`1 previousPayloads, ProtocolErrorBehavior protocolErrorBehavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Protocol/Serialization/ProtocolUtility.cs:line 480
       at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 956
       at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 133
       at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 108
       at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 456
       at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 56
       at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 331
       at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 323
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at EventManager.Server.Controllers.ParticipantController.GetSessions() in C:\Users\CMSB\Desktop\EventManager\EventManager.Server\Controllers\ParticipantController.cs:line 173
```

**Edit:**
I also have an issue querying the dashboard API. It used to work at the beginning, but then when I deploy the server, after a while, now even the dasboard I cannot retrieve.

This is the Get request for dashboard:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[ValidateReferrerAttribute]
public async Task<Event> GetForDashboard(Guid id)
{
    if (await _entities.AnyAsync(x => x.EventId == id))
    {
        var data = await _entities
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.CheckIns)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Participant)
            .Include(x => x.Participants)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Feedbacks)
            .Include(x => x.Sessions)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Speakers)
            .Include(x => x.Sessions)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Participants)
            .Include(x => x.Sessions)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.CheckIns)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Participant)
            .FirstAsync(x => x.EventId == id);

        return data;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: When including multiple collections you can try using `.AsSplitQuery()` to improve performance. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.assplitquery?view=efcore-6.0). As always, profile to see if it really improves your case..

Comment: Thank you @CarlesCompany. After I added this to my query, now I can access both workshops for event and dashboard. I quickly deployed this change to the server in an ongoing event. Please submit as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When including multiple collections you can try using `.AsSplitQuery()` to improve performance. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.assplitquery?view=efcore-6.0). As always, profile to see if it really improves your case..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this. Execute to get the user first (to get the user Id). the point here is to use the Id to query.
By convention, the Id column is often indexed, so query by the Id has a better performance. It should solve the time-out issue

```
var user = _entities
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);

if(user != null) 
{
   return await _entities
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.CheckIns)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Session)
            .Include(x => x.Events)
            .Include(x => x.Sessions)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Event)
            .Include(x => x.Sessions)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Speakers)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Avatar)
            .Include(x => x.Sessions)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Materials)
            .ProjectTo<ParticipantSessionDto>(configuration)
            .FirstAsync(x => x.Id == user.Id);
}
```

Updated to optimize the Include query
Maybe the problems come from several `Include` expressions. You can optimized the query by using the [Entity Framework Core Plus Include Optimize](https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-query-include-optimized)

```
return await _entities
            .AsNoTracking()
            .IncludeOptimized(x => x.CheckIns)
            .IncludeOptimized(x => x.CheckIns.Select(y => y.Session))
            .IncludeOptimized(x => x.Events)
            .IncludeOptimized(x => x.Sessions)
            .IncludeOptimized(x => x.Sessions.Select(y => y.Event))
            // And so on
            .ProjectTo<ParticipantSessionDto>(configuration)
            .FirstAsync(x => x.Id == user.Id);
```

Comment: Is there a difference in performance querying id or username? Do you think if I switch to querying the id, it will solve the timeout issue?

Comment: @Ibrahim The Id must be the PK of the User table, and in MySQL, the primary key is always indexed. you will query faster using the indexed column

Comment: Thank you Bao, if you look into my edited question, you will see that I query using primary key for the dashboard query, and I still get the timeout error. Therefore, using primary key query does not solve the issue.

Comment: Maybe the issue arises from the several relations that im including. At first its working, but now with more data accumulated, the same API results in command timeout

Comment: @Ibrahim I updated the answer, maybe you can try to follow it to optimize your query

Comment: Thank you. Your answer looks promising. Can you help me with final part to convert to IncludeOptimized.
`Include(x => x.Sessions).ThenInclude(x => x.CheckIns) .ThenInclude(x => x.Participant)`

Comment: @Ibrahim in EF 6 you can use multiple Select to include the nested object. `.Include(x => x.Sessions.Select(y => y.CheckIns.Select(z => z.Participant)))`. Can I have an upvote for this. Thank you :D